# class RepositoryPropertyReferenceController is not visible outside it's package

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

class [RepositoryPropertyReferenceController](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.java)  is not visible outside it's package, and no same package controller is extending it  either. Yet the mappings it provides, namely handling requests of  resources' relationships is fully functional in default `spring-data-rest`. I am trying to build a custom Base Controller with Generics and want to implement the functionality that this controller provides,yet there's no clear way for me to extend from it because of it's restricted visibility.

Comment: You can create your public class by using the same package name (`org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc`) and then extend others from it.

Comment: or extend AbstractRepositoryRestController and give your implementation

Comment: I cannot extend from it because I cannot import this package, it's not public. Never mind about me using it, my question has to do with how this class is useful at all in Spring since I have not found any other class extending from it. It's used only in tests.